# The dialog box will not stop, what is the problem with my code?

Tags: java, arrays, stack

```java
import javax.swing.*;
public class StackExer1 {

    public int arr [];
    public int getSize(){
        int size;
       String input=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Size");
       size=Integer.parseInt(input);
       arr=new int[size];
       return size;    
    }
     public int voidpush() {

       for(int x=0;x<arr.length;x++){
           String input2=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Push a number");
            int num=Integer.parseInt(input2); 
            arr[x]=num;
             System.out.print(arr[x]+" ");
       }
       return voidpush();
     }

    public static void main (String args []){

      StackExer1 an=new StackExer1();
      an.getSize();
      an.voidpush();


    }
}
```

Once I run this, the dialog box Push a number will not stop, example if I enter 5 in the size dialog box. the second dialog box will not stop.

Comment: Your `return voidpush();` at the end of that method just starts the method all over again.  You need to return something different.

Answer (score 0):

Your voidpush() method return is calling the method again and therefore it works continuously,try making the method as void as suggested below and run your code.

```
import javax.swing.*;
public class StackExer1 {

    public int arr [];
    public int getSize(){
        int size;
        String input=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter Size");
        size=Integer.parseInt(input);
        arr=new int[size];
        return size;
    }
    public void voidpush() {

        for(int x=0;x<arr.length;x++){
            String input2=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Push a number");
            int num=Integer.parseInt(input2);
            arr[x]=num;
            System.out.print(arr[x]+" ");
        }

    }

    public static void main (String args []){

        StackExer1 an=new StackExer1();
        an.getSize();
        an.voidpush();


    }
}
```

Comment: @WakigzBatangOtnak best way to thank is accept this answer as correct!